# How to access POST variables in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not really a Rails developer and I'm working on someone else's code.

Anyway, I'm trying to change the login function so that it uses POST instead of GET. Right now it looks like this:

```
def login
  email = params[:email];
  password = params[:password];
  # login logic ...
end
```

What do I need to change to use POST variables instead?

**EDIT:** The line that looked relevant in `routes.rb`

```
match "service/login", :to => "service#login"
```

If there's something else I'm looking for, please let me know.

Comment: It's not the controller that you have to change, but the routes (in `config/routes.rb`).

Comment: Please show what exists in config/routes.rb, particularly is there are any line for user.  Also please let us know which version of rails (e.g. 2.3.8 or 3.0) you have (check the Gemfile at root [v3] or config/environment.rb [v2] for this info).  if you can get to rails command line, e.g. script/rails console [v3] or script/console [v2], then 'Rake routes' whoch show all the routes too which is incredibly handy.

Comment: btw you can access the variables with either GET or POST  Is there a greater reason for your question? Security perhaps (I'm guessing, to avoid u/p in URL's)?

Comment: Please post the related routes and the view for the form that posts to the login action, it should be easy to help you then.

Comment: @Michael, Rails 3.0 and yes I want to avoid u/p in URL's.

Comment: @Benoit, This is the line I found in `routes.rb` that looked relevant: `match "service/login", :to => "service#login"`

Comment: (Not that switching to POST is any more secure, although at least you can't bookmark it, I suppose.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
match "service/login", :to => "service#login"
```

to:

```
match "service/login", :to => "service#login", :via => :post
```

or (shorter):

```
post "service/login"
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
match "service/login", :to => "service#login", :via => :post
```

and don't forget to use `:method => :post` in your login form :)