# How can I retrieve and save Twilio responses in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

So a user calls a Twilio phone number. Twilio looks for a `voice_url` attached to that number (from their dashboard) and sees some XML with instructions on how to handle the call. The XML file also has an "action" parameter that points to a url.

Ideally, this URL should be able to retrieve parameters sent by Twilio and save them to a DB. This is where I'm stuck; how can I see which parameters are sent and how can I save them? I'm assuming the URL in the "action" parameter points to a controller?

I'm using the twilio-rb gem.

Some relevant links:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action
http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request

Answer (score 2):

When Twilio makes a POST to the URL mentioned by the Action parameter, it will send all of the attributes mentioned here: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request.

You should create your own route and controller for responding to the incoming Twilio request. When Twilio makes the request, you should be able to get the variables out of the POST request like any POST request. See for example [How to access POST variables in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389661/how-to-access-post-variables-in-rails).